# Access violation when trying to populate an array of struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

Original code comment specifying the core question:

> The error I am getting is while iterating through the while loop,
>   memory out of range or something... resizing to 300 ... Access
>   violation writing location that's the exact Fraze...

I'm trying to implement a faster .Net `List<T>` equivalent in C.

I'm using blittable data types in C#.

In the code below I've moved a function body to the main function just for testing  after I have failed to understand where am I wrong.

The problem seems to be that **inside the `while` loop**  `UntArr` does not increment.
What am I doing wrong?

```
typedef struct {
    int Id;
    char *StrVal;
}Unit; // a data unit as element of an array

unsigned int startTimer(unsigned int start);
unsigned int stopTimer(unsigned int start);

int main(){

Unit *UntArr= {NULL};
//Unit test[30000];

//decelerations comes first..
char *dummyStringDataObject;
int adummyNum,requestedMasterArrLength,requestedStringSize,MasterDataArrObjectMemorySize,elmsz;
int TestsTotalRounds, TestRoundsCounter,ccountr;
unsigned int start, stop, mar;

//Data Settings (manually for now)
requestedMasterArrLength=300;
requestedStringSize = 15;

//timings
start=0;stop=0;
//data sizes varies (x86/x64) compilation according to fastest results
MasterDataArrObjectMemorySize = sizeof(UntArr);
elmsz= sizeof(UntArr[0]);

TestRoundsCounter=-1;
start = startTimer(start);

while(++TestRoundsCounter<requestedMasterArrLength){
    int count;
    count=-1;
    //allocate memory for the "Master Arr"
    UntArr = (Unit *)malloc(sizeof(Unit)*requestedMasterArrLength);
    dummyStringDataObject = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*requestedStringSize);
    dummyStringDataObject = "abcdefgHijkLmNo";
    while (++count<requestedMasterArrLength)
    {
        dummyStringDataObject[requestedStringSize-1]=count+'0';
        puts(dummyStringDataObject);

        ccountr=-1;
        // tried
        UntArr[count].Id = count;
        UntArr[count].StrVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*requestedStringSize);
        UntArr[count].StrVal = dummyStringDataObject;// as a whole 
        //while(++ccountr<15)// one by one cause a whole won't work ?
        //UntArr[count].StrVal[ccountr] = dummyStringDataObject[ccountr];

    }

free(UntArr);free(dummyStringDataObject);

}
stop = startTimer(start);
mar = stop - start;


MasterDataArrObjectMemorySize = sizeof(UntArr)/1024;
printf("Time taken in millisecond: %d ( %d sec)\r\n size: %d kb\r\n", mar,(mar/1000),MasterDataArrObjectMemorySize);
printf("UntArr.StrVal: %s",UntArr[7].StrVal);

getchar();

return 0;
}



 unsigned int startTimer(unsigned int start){
     start = clock();
     return start;
 }
 unsigned int stopTimer(unsigned int start){
     start = clock()-start;
     return start;
 }
```

testing the code one by one instead of within a while loop work as expected

```
//allocate memory for the "Master Arr"
UntArr = (Unit *)malloc(sizeof(Unit)*requestedMasterArrLength);
UntArr[0].Id = 0;
dummyStringDataObject = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*requestedStringSize);

dummyStringDataObject = "abcdefgHijkLmNo";

////allocate memory for the string object
UntArr[0].StrVal = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*requestedStringSize);
////test string manipulation
adummyNum=5;
UntArr[0].StrVal= dummyStringDataObject;
//
UntArr[0].StrVal[14] = adummyNum+'0';
////test is fine
```

Comment: I read your post, and it's too long for the average person on SO; you should try to reduce your sentences to the information contained, and remove the chatter.

Comment: also, make your code a minimal example, and format it more nicely, to enhance readability

Comment: `dummyStringDataObject = "abcdefgHijkLmNo";` should be `strcpy(dummyStringDataObject, "abcdefgHijkLmNo");`. The same with `UntArr[count].StrVal = dummyStringDataObject;`.

Comment: You're never freeing all the `StrVal`s before you free `UntArr`.

Comment: `while` expressions with side effects via `++` operations immediately have me stop reading. Don't do such things. This buys you nothing (but trouble).

Comment: Use a `for()` loop instead of `while` to make @JensGustedt happy.

Comment: @mch include<string.h> trying to minimize to using chars only

Comment: @JensGustedt: The `while (++x < n)` is *the least problematic* part of the code. In fact, I consider that sort of thing fairly readable.

Comment: @EOF, I can't know, I didn't continue ...

Comment: @JensGustedt Well `MasterDataArrObjectMemorySize = sizeof(UntArr);` is *before* the `while()`.

Comment: @EOF and everyone here @ barmar, @ jens, & marcus . thanks . @ marcus i will edit the code . every one pleas try to really help. thank you.

Comment: @mch has it. The assignment `str = "abc"` is legal, but it's not what the OP wants. The `malloc`ed memory is lost and when the string is altered, the program tries to modify write-only memory.

Comment: As @MarcusMüller, you've hidden the true question in a code comment. And why so many lines of commented-out code? Are they relevant, or not? If they are, show the actual code giving problems, if not, remove them.

Comment: that's a nice start , LoneXcoder, but seeing that this seems to be as far as your shortening efforts seem to go, I'll have the audacity of redacting your text.

Comment: I think I've shortened LoneXcoder's prose without removing information content.

Comment: By the way, I think optimizing microsoft's native containers is pretty much highly insane -- it's very unlikely those weren't highly optimized in the first place.

Comment: **"memory out of range or something"** you should seriously, and in verbatim, reproduce that error in your question -- it will point you to what goes wrong immediately.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what do you think about the discovery ? , never mind the issue of the question, `c` is sharper than `C#` as expected... though `c++` is even better ? is that so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it happens and as i am new to pointers i have not realize that when debugging 
i will not see the elements of given pointer to an array as i am used to 
with normal `Array[]` but looping through result which i did not even try as when i was hovering  above the `Array*`  within the while loop expecting to see the elements as in a normal array:

`Data[]  DataArr = new Data[1000]` <- i have expected to actually see the body of the array while looping and populating the `Data*` and did not realize it is not an actual array but a pointer to one so you can not see the elements/body.

the solution is via a function now as planed originally :

```
void dodata(int requestedMasterArrLength,int requestedStringSize){

    int ccountr,count;
    count=0;
    UntArr=NULL;
    UntArr = (Unit *)malloc(sizeof(Unit)*requestedMasterArrLength);

        while(count!=requestedMasterArrLength)
        {
                char dummyStringDataObject[]= "abcdefgHi";

                UntArr[count].StrVal=NULL;  

                dummyStringDataObject[requestedStringSize-1] = count+'0';
                UntArr[count].Id= count;
                ccountr=0;
                UntArr[count].StrVal= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*requestedStringSize);
                    while(ccountr!=requestedStringSize){
                        UntArr[count].StrVal[ccountr] = dummyStringDataObject[ccountr];
                        ++ccountr;
                    }
            ++count;
        }


}
```

generaly speaking, `x86` compilation would get better performance for this current task , populating an array of a struct.
so i have compiled it also in `c++` and `c#`.

executing similar code in `C#`  and `C++`

minimum time measured in `c#` ~ 3,100 ms.

minimum time measured in this code - `C` ~ 1700 ms.

minimum time measured in `C++` ~ 900 ms.

i was surprised to see this last result c++ is the winner but why.
i thought c is closer to the system level, CPU, Memory...

Comment: Yes, C *is* closer to the machine. So the performance of C-code depends on how well the programmer understands what modern computers *actually do*. In other words, bad C-code will run slowly.